# Python QtCreator and Slots

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator

I cannot figure out how to use a simple button,

I used:

> QtCreator>New Project>Application>Qt for Python - Window(UIFile)

And name everything test.
I opened `form.ui` and drag in a button
I press run and a window with a button shows.

But I cannot get that button to run any code from main.py, I have searched and spent hours upon hours, I know its something simple, I have tried with slots and it just tells me the slot doesn't exist, if I right click the button and press go to slot I just get an error:

> error no "ui_form.h"

There must be something I am overlooking, if someone could please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Post some code, screenshots, sources you've referred to, etc.